# Count Down Stoped After Changed the Date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I was trying to implement count down timer for my web site. I want to give two static dates to and get the count down running. I found an example that uses one hard code date and the other date is taken as new Date() . but when I change that new Date() to Hard Code values count down timer stopped . How to fix this issue .

[Original Example I found in jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/vvGPQ/1/)

[My modified Example in jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/chamaraxxxo/3kLch5jb/1/)

the only difference in those examples is i changed `var date1 = new Date();`   to `var date1 = new Date("2017/07/22 20:30:00");`

Comment: Please include any relevant code in your questions as it increases the chances of it being answered substantially. People do not like to go to possibly dangerous links.

Comment: @Jhecht those are Js fiddle links

Comment: That's great, but people are still less likely to click on the links. There is a snippet editor here on StackOverflow that is very similar to JSFiddle, if you could be so kind please add them in

Comment: if you are giving static dates then at every interval you need to update any of you date

Comment: The code is working fine. There is no problem here

Comment: @Tân if you look closely at my example timer is stoped.orginal example timer is running

Comment: Just checking it via `console.log(diff)`, you will see it's really *working*.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dates that you provided will never change since you are continually calling the same function each interval (i.e. the difference between `date1` and `date2` will never change).

If you want a countdown, you'll need to use some relatively changing date similar to the original example you provided or retain an offset (i.e. store when you started the process and continually use an offset for your calculations) as seen below:

```js
// Store a relative date to track passing time
var started = new Date();

showDiff();

function showDiff() {
  // Keep track of the time that has elapsed
  var offset = new Date() - started;

  // Store your dates
  var date1 = new Date("2017/07/22 20:30:00") - offset;
  var date2 = new Date("2015/07/30 21:59:00");
  
  // Calculate the differences
  var diff = Math.abs(Math.floor((date2 - date1) / 1000));

  var days = Math.floor(diff / (24 * 60 * 60));
  var daysLeft = diff - days * 24 * 60 * 60;

  var hours = Math.floor(daysLeft / (60 * 60));
  var hoursLeft = daysLeft - hours * 60 * 60;

  var minutes = Math.floor(hoursLeft / (60));
  var minutesLeft = hoursLeft - minutes * 60;
  
  var seconds = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
  var secondsLeft = minutesLeft - seconds * 60;
  
  // Output
  document.getElementById("showTime").innerHTML = "You have " + days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes and " + secondsLeft + " seconds before death.";

  setTimeout(showDiff, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id='showTime'></div>
```

Comment: Upvote for the description. Not related to the question but do you think the way to name variable `var diff` (twice) is weird?

Comment: Yes - it is strange. It was just copied over from the original answer as I wasn't terribly concerned with the other code (just the relative time portion). I'll clean it up a bit for the sake of OP.